# Idea for weekly topic challenge: Bein haMetzarim

Tags: discussion

I propose questions relating to Bein HaMetzarim (i.e. "the Three Weeks") as a new idea for a weekly discussion topic on our site.  We would discuss the following topics and more via our site's Q&A format:

- [Tisha B'Av](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tisha_B%27Av)
- [Fasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%27anit)
- [Kinnot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinnot)
- [Mourning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bereavement_in_Judaism)

Potential tags that will be used include [three-weeks](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-weeks), [nine-days](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nine-days), [mourning-aveilus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mourning-aveilus) and [churban-destruction](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/churban-destruction)

Comment: Could you post the [meta-tag:topic-challenge-proposal] and the [meta-tag:feature-request] (which I assume is about all weekly topics, not just this one (but even if I'm wrong)) as two separate questions, please, so that if people upvote/downvote your question then everyone else will know which aspect of it they were voting on?

Comment: @AA, msh210 - Thank you for the good edits.